# Função is_dir() não funciona como esperado

Tags: php, diretório, sistema-de-arquivos

Saudações!
Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de arquivos para ler os arquivos de um determinado diretório e retornar o valor em JSON. No entanto, pretendo separar nesse JSON se o item é um arquivo (`"type":"file"`) ou uma pasta(`"type":"folder"`).
Para isso, estou usando a função `is_dir()` (tentei também com a função `is_file()`). Maass... Não funcionou, obtendo o seguinte resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que utilizei:

```php
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  $path = str_replace("\\", "/", './root');
  $dir  = dir($path);
  $json = array();

  while($file = $dir -> read()){
    if ($file != ".." && $file != "."){
      array_push(
        $json,
        array(
          'path'=>$path.'/'.$file,
          'file'=>$file,
          'type'=>(!is_dir($file)) ? 'file' : 'folder'
        )
      );
    }
  }

  echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: OBS: Eu também testei utilizando `dirname(__FILE__)` no lugar de `./` na variável `$path` (por isso está dentro do `str_replace()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o problema:
A função `is_dir()` retorna `false` se o arquivo especificado não existir e parte da pasta em que o arquivo `.php` está sendo executado, ou seja, eu estava escaneando os arquivos da pasta `./` e não da pasta `./root`.
Encontrei este problema testando com a função `file_exists($file)` e obtendo também um resultado `false`.
**A solução seria utilizar como parâmetro da função o caminho completo do arquivo.** Ou seja: utilizar `is_dir($path.'/'.$file)` e não apenas `is_dir($file)`, dessa forma o Php encontra o arquivo e se torna capaz de verificá-lo.